# require is not defined in app.js for laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to use Laravel Passport in my project, I have followed this tutorial of Laravel Passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport.

After following this tutorial, I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined** error.

Please have a look into my files :

1. gulpfile.js

   ```
   var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
   require('laravel-elixir-webpack');

   elixir(function(mix) {

       mix.scripts('app.js');

       mix.styles([
                   'bootstrap.min.css',
                   'font-awesome.min.css',
                   'gentelella.min.css'
                  ],'public/css/app.css');

   });
   ```
2. resource/assets/js/app.js

   ```
   Vue.component(
       'passport-clients',
       require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
   );

   Vue.component(
       'passport-authorized-clients',
       require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
   );

   Vue.component(
       'passport-personal-access-tokens',
       require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
   );

   const app = new Vue({
       el: '#manage-passport'
   });
   ```
3. home.blade.php

   ```
   @extends('layouts.blank')
   @section('content')

   <div class="container" id="manage-passport">

     <!-- let people make clients -->
       <passport-clients></passport-clients>

       <!-- list of clients people have authorized to access our account -->
       <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>

       <!-- make it simple to generate a token right in the UI to play with -->
       <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
   </div>

   @stop
   ```
4. blank.blade.php

   ```
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

       <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

       <title>Passport! | </title>

       <meta name="token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
       <!-- Styles -->
       <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

   </head>

   <body class="nav-md">
       <div class="container body">
           <div class="main_container">
               @yield('content')
           </div>
       </div>

       <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/gentelella.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
       <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>

       @stack('scripts')

   </body>
   ```

Comment: did u gulp after changes?

Comment: yes, but its showing me error.

Comment: how did you gulp? seems like you didn't gulp, else you won't get that error.

Comment: Change `mix.scripts` to `mix.wekpack`

Comment: when i change  to mix.wekpack, gulp gives me following error.

Error in Clients.vue
Module parse failed at Clients.vue .
 Unexpected token
you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
SyntaxError : unexpected token

Comment: Sorry that was meant to be `webpack`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem in the absence of token?

blank.blade.php

```
<script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token()]) !!}
</script>
```

also, check whether the transmitted parameters such as token

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});
```

Comment: You showed all the code in file resource/assets/js/app.js ?

Comment: This is because the parameters are not set token
You may be more clearly create a new project for the instructions and [see how it connects token](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13)
Or at least look like set [parameters](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js) @SwapnilChaudhari

Comment: If csrf token is not there, you will get csrf token missmatch exception.